# Accessing a State in one Context from another Context

Tags: reactjs

I current have two Contexts. The first has a "gallery" state.

How do I access the "gallery" state in a another context and update it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the setter to the context as well and access the setter from whatever component you want and use it there.

Comment: Hi Sorry, do you happen to have an example of this? Much appreciated!